# Hardwood to Laminate floor transition

Tags: hardwood, laminate-floor, transition

We recently purchased this house and it has hardwood in the entryway but the rest of the room is carpet. We don't want to spend money on hardwood floor and want to put laminate. Do you'll think the transition from hardwood to laminate will look hideous? Or should I remove the hardwood? Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue will be the height difference from the hardwood to laminate and a moulding to cover the transition.  Depending on the height of the hardwood, you are at least looking at a half inch difference (at minimum) between the wood and laminate.  And the moulding might also be a trip hazard for any older people as they enter/leave your house.

My personal choice would be to remove the section of hardwood to remove the above two issues.

Comment: I agree.  Also most entry ways would have multiple sides needing a transition.  That would really look terrible.